# Is there any requirement for the participation of Stack Exchange 2.0 moderators to the meta site for the site where they are moderators?

Tags: support, moderators, per-site-meta

Is there a minimal participation that moderators on a Stack Exchange 2.0 site are supposed to have on the meta site associated to the site they are moderating? I am not referring to Stack Exchange staff, but to appointed moderators and moderators that have been elected on any of the Stack Exchange site that are not part of the trilogy.

I have noticed that in some sites, the moderators answer questions on the meta site, while in other cases, the moderators barely answer any question on the meta site, with the exception of requests to merge accounts.

While I understand that always having an answer from a moderator could have the effect of stopping other users from answering those questions, especially on sites with a restricted number of  frequent visitors, I also think that moderators that never reply to questions about why they closed a question, or why the flag about an answer that is not really an answer was rejected, don't participate to the meta site enough.

Is there any requirement for the moderators' participation to the meta site? What is the limit between non participating, and participating too few?
What about the participation to Meta Stack Overflow? Are moderators supposed to have a minimal knowledge of what is suggested on Meta Stack Overflow for some of the basic (or less basic) operations done from a user (e.g. flag two user accounts from merging, flag all the comments of an answer as obsolete) and the preferred way to do it (e.g. flag the post created from one of the account, and report the account should be merged with another one; flag the post to which the comments are referring, and report that those comments are all off-topic/too chatty)?

Comment: Well, they are required to have the [Convention](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/901/convention) badge in order to be elected for that site, but I don't know about continued participation after that.

Comment: Is that requirement valid for any Stack Exchange 2.0 site?

Comment: Questions posted on a meta site are included in the Moderators' inbox notifications, so if it's not a requirement it's at least strongly encouraged.

Comment: @animuson That requirement was only for the Stack Overflow elections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moderators are encouraged by the management to ensure that each and every meta post receives some kind of response.

- Sometimes we just post a comment linking to a discussion on the mother meta.
- Sometimes we note that a non-moderator has already addressed the issue.
- Some we handle ourselves.

As Al Everett noted in the comments this is facilitated by treating them as activity in the moderators queue. When meta.physics.SE is active I get a lot of notifications – hopefully meta.stackoverflow.com is treated differently or the SO mods must be inundated.

Comment: No, we don't get notifications when there are new posts on Meta.  (My thanks go out to the dev who implemented that feature.)

Comment: I take they are encouraged, but there isn't a minimum required participation.